# Why doesn't double equal works for the for loop condition whereas less than equals works in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop

Why doesn't double equal work in Java?

```
    int end = 10;
    int start =0;
    
    for(int i=start;i==end;i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
```

Whereas the following works?

```
    int end = 10;
    int start =0;
    
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop with the equal-operator will never be entered, because `i==end` (i.e. `0==10`) is false on the first iteration of the loop, whereas `i<=end` (i.e. `0<=10`) is not.

The for loop:

```
for(i=start; i<=end; ++i) {
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
i=start;
while(i<=end) {
    ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be misunderstood on how a for loop works. Then syntax of a for loop is
`for(A;B;C)`
where B is a boolean.
The loop will continue to work until B is false.
if you have `i == end`, then it does not execute because i is not equal to end in the first place
when you have `i <= end` which works until i is greater than end.